# Error while zipping a directory in perl

Tags: perl

I couldn't find a question relevant to the error i am facing.
Please apologise if it was there for i couldn't find the same.

I am facing an error while zipping a directory in Perl. The error is

"The stat preceding -1 _ wasn't an 1stat at c:/Perl/site/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 2885.".

Below is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

my $directory = 'D:\MyBooks\Data\Super Folder';

my $obj = Archive::Zip->new();

opendir (DIR, $directory) or die $!;

my @filearray = readdir(DIR);

close(DIR);


foreach my $file(@filearray)
{

    $obj->addFile($file);   # add files
}


if ($obj->writeToFileNamed('dummy.zip') == AZ_OK) 
{  

    print "Archive created successfully!";
} 
else 
{

    print "Error while Zipping !";
}
```

Comment: You may wish to check that you are adding files.  readdir will give you everything in the directory, including the . and .. directories.

Comment: The `-w` in your shebang and the `use warnings` are equivalent. You should drop one. Preferrably the one in the shebang as it's clearer to read the `use` statement.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're getting the list of files in `D:\MyBooks\Data\Super Folder`, but you're telling Archive::Zip to zip files in the current directory.
2. You say you want to store an entire directory tree, but you don't even attempt to do that.

Going by the docs, you want:

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my $dir_qfn = 'D:\MyBooks\Data\Super Folder';
for my $qfn ( File::Find::Rule->new->relative->in($dir_qfn) ) {
   $archive->addFileOrDirectory("$dir_qfn/$qfn", $qfn);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not putting my question clearly. The Directory contains Sub Directories as well. i need the files as well as Sub Directories. I need to zip the complete directory the way it is.

Comment: Updated my answer. In the future, if you have a new question, ask a new question.